# Wraptable width according to table width

Tags: tables, wrapfigure

Is there a way to set the width of a wraptable to the width of the tabular that it is containing rather than setting a specified width?

```
\begin{wraptable}{r}{8cm}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
& Fibonacci Heap & Binary Heap \\ \midrule
\texttt{insert} & \bigO{1} (amortized) & \bigO{\log{n}} \\ \midrule
\texttt{decreaseKey} & \bigO{1} (amortized) & \bigO{n} \\ \midrule
\texttt{deleteMin} & \bigO{1} (amortized) & \bigO{\log{n}} \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{The runtime efficiency of different Priority Queues}\label{tabular:priorityQueuesRuntime}
\end{wraptable}
```

Thanks for any help!

PS: don't think about the runtimes of the algorithms (if you can relate to them), they're *wrong*!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From wrapfig's documentation:

> ### 2 Sizing and optional overhang
>
> Parameter #4 (the second required parameter) is the width of the
>   figure or table. [...]
>
> However, if you specify a width of zero (0pt), the actual width of the
>   figure will determine the wrapping width. A following `\caption` should
>   have the same width as the figure, but it might fail badly; it is
>   safer to specify a width when you use a caption.

Try `\begin{wraptable}{r}{0pt} ...`.  And please provide a MWE and not code snippets.

Comment: While this works to adjust the width, it somehow negates `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` that aligned the wraptable with the first line of text. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @EmeraJade - `wrapfig` adds a gap of `\intextsep` at the top and bottom (check the manual).  I'm not sure what exactly you're looking for, maybe you open up a new question.

Comment: I figured it out thanks to this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258957/131277